How to create Datasets in airflow only for specific tables?
I have code of my dag like below:
imports....


START_DATE = datetime(2024, 4, 21)
SAP_COPY_DATASET = "mydataset"
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "0 8 * * *"
TAGS = ["SAP_ERP"]
DAG_ID = "sap_erp_import__other_tables"

default_args = {
    some args...
}

DEPENDS_ON_ONE = {
    "0ART_SALES_ATTR",
    "0VEN_COMPC_ATTR",
    "0VEN_PURORG_ATTR",
    "0VENDOR_TEXT",
    "AUFK",
    "AUSP",
    "BSAK",
    "EKBE",
    "EKKN",
    "EKKO_Archived",
    "KONDN",
    "KOTN201",
    "MCHB",
    "YBIF_MSG_LOMMLOG",
    "YYLOMMLOGD",
    "ZBIF_SHOP_OV",
    "ZKBC_CDHDRPOS_01",
    "ZWM_PUT_STOCK_CA",
    "T006A",
    "ZBW_CAT_FILTER",
    "CABN",
    "CAWN",
    "INOB",
    "LINP",
    "MEAN",
    "RMA_VBAP",
    "T001L",
    "T042Z",
    "T300T",
    "TVAKT",
    "VBAK",
    "WAKH_WAKP",
    "XAP_IDLVH",
    "XAP_IDLVR",
    "YIMR_ADVICE_I",
    "YIMR_PACK_LOG",
    "YIMR_SERNR_STATA",
    "YIMR_SERNR_STAT",
    "YIMR_SNSTAT_CT",
    "YIMR_WCS_LOG",
    "YIMR_WCS_MSG_LOG",
    "YRMA_CT_SERVCMT",
    "YWG_CALENDAR",
    "YWG_GIFT_ITEM",
    "YWG_SET",
    "YWG_SET_ITEM",
    "YWG_SET_PRICE",
    "YWG_VAR_PARAM",
    "ZLO_EXT_PUP",
    "ZVBAP_SERVICES",
    "YWA_VAR_LABEL",
    "KONBBYPRQ",
    "KONMATGRPP",
    "ZLO_IMP_TASHA",
    "YIMR_INVWM",
    "ZLO_DEL_CAN_LOGH",
    "ZLO_DEL_CAN_LOGI",
    "ZFI_CANC_AD_TEXT",
    "ZFI_CANC_ADVICE",
    "0COSTCENTER_TEXT",
    "0GL_ACCOUNT_TEXT",
    "0PROFIT_CTR_TEXT"
}

DEPENDS_ON_MANY = [
    ({"VBAK_TEST_DATA_NON_UE", "VBKD"}, "VBKD"),
    ({"T002", "T002T"}, "T002")
]

with DAG(
    dag_params...
) as dag:

    dummy_end = DummyOperator(task_id="end")

    # one-to-one models
    for model in sorted(DEPENDS_ON_ONE):

        sensor = BQTable.from_str(f"{SAP_COPY_DATASET}.{model}").get_observed_sensor(
            date="{{ data_interval_end | ds }}",
            mut_types=[MutationType.EDIT],
            obj_types=[ObjectType.TABLES],
            env=BigQueryObserverEnvironment.PROD,
            dag=dag
        )

        mart = DBTRunOperator(
                task_id=model,
                dag_filepath=__file__,
                models=[f"+{model}"],
                profile=const.PROFILE,
                target=const.ENV,
            )


        sensor >> mart >> dummy_end

    # many to one models
    for sources, model in sorted(DEPENDS_ON_MANY, key=lambda x: x[1]):

        mart = DBTRunOperator(
            task_id=model,
            dag_filepath=__file__,
            models=[f"+{model}"],
            profile=const.PROFILE,
            target=const.ENV,
        )

        for source in sorted(sources):
            sensor = BQTable.from_str(f"{SAP_COPY_DATASET}.{source}").get_observed_sensor(
                date="{{ data_interval_end | ds }}",
                mut_types=[MutationType.EDIT],
                obj_types=[ObjectType.TABLES],
                env=BigQueryObserverEnvironment.PROD,
                dag=dag
            )

            sensor >> mart >> dummy_end

I would like to create only 4 datasets from given tables which are on DEPENDS_ON_ONE list:
KONDN, KOTN201, KONBBYPRQ and KONMATGRPP in mart task.
I was thinking if I could use there outlets parameter inside of "mart"? Or maybe it should be totally separate and create new task between them or after any of them?
How can I do it using Airflow datasets?
